# How to display images of different height in listview on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, listview, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

Does anyone know how to develop something like this on Windows Phone 8?
http://sdrv.ms/17PUTs4 "Snapshot of an existing app"

I know I can use WrapPanel to get multi-column list view but I don't know how could I get different height for each list view item

Comment: What have you tried? The screenshot you've provided definitely isn't using a standard ListBox or LongListSelector item template. At least not in a way that doesn't remove all possibility of virtualization. If that's the case it's just three columns in a scrollviewer.

Answer (score 0):

I see that listBox in sample app is divided into 3 columns - it's easy to do. 
Next:
Each column should be filled with imagecontainers with HorizontalAligment="stretch" to get columns width, images Height set to auto so that with resizing the width the height would be set automaticaly so that there were no unproportional resizes. And image Stretch property to Uniform.

Something like:

```
<Image Name="BackButton" Source="BackButton.png" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="auto"/>
```

Addition:

To get that kind of list box, i suggest you using MS ExpressionBlend to make custom user control